# Remove Interval in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm doing a very little clock for practice with Backbone but i'm not able to stop it.. I'm trying to stop it by returning the id of the current interval, but it doesn't work.  What i'm doing wrong?

```
   var app = {
    lap: Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
       time: 0
     }
    }),
    views: {
      home: Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#the-clock'),
        tagName: 'div',
        events: {
          "click #save-lap" : "stopWatch"
      },
      render: function(){
         var time = this.theWatch(),
             tpl = '<button id="save-lap"></button><span id="clock">Son las <%= time %></span>';

         $(this.el).html( _.template(tpl,time));
      },
        theWatch: function(){
          var currentTime = new Date(),
              currentHour = currentTime.getHours(),
              currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes(),
              currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds(),
              timeOfDay = (currentHour < 12) ? "AM":"PM";

          return data = {
              time: currentHour + ':' + currentMinutes + ':' + currentSeconds + ' ' + timeOfDay
          }
      },
      updateWatch: function(){
          return setInterval(
              function(){
                  this.render();
              }.bind(this),
              1000
          )
      },
      stopWatch: function(){
          console.log('stop')
          var clock = this.updateWatch();
          clearInterval(clock);
      },
      initialize: function(){
          this.render();
          this.updateWatch();
      }
  })
},
ini: function(){
  var Home = new this.views.home();
}
};

 (function(){
    app.ini();
  })();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling this.updateWatch(), you are creating a new interval each time you want to stop! Try this instead:

```
updateWatch: function(){
    return setInterval(
        function(){
            this.render();
        }.bind(this),
        1000
    )
},
stopWatch: function(){
    clearInterval(this.clockInterval);
},
initialize: function(){
    this.render();
    this.clockInterval = this.updateWatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating the 'Interval' object every time you call updateWatch.

Instead, you need to store the result of setInterval in a property; and re-use that when you want to stop it.